# Why is my IEX API request not going through?

Tags: api, url, web-scraping, stock, elixir-iex

I'm planning to use the IEX Cloud api with a finance application. I was testing it with this query: https://www.iexcloud.io/v1/stock/aapl/1y&token=pk_4b288536af684768ab46ea629b480ece
I also tried https://www.iexcloud.io/v1/stock/aapl/1y?token=pk_4b288536af684768ab46ea629b480ece (changed & to ?). Each time it says 'forbidden.' What could be my problem(s)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the SandBox View on as the testing key does not work if it is off
I did this in Ruby on Rails and it work's for me

```
client = IEX::Api::Client.new(
   publishable_token: 'api key',
   endpoint: 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/v1'
)
```

After that, I used the client to find out the stock price

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to first check "Sandbox View" to "ON", on the left navigation bar. This will reset your tokens.

[image]

Then use the following with the right credentials in your console:

```
client = IEX::Api::Client.new(
  publishable_token: 'Tpk_YoUrPuBlIcToKeN',
  secret_token: 'Tsk_YoUrSeCrEtToKeN',
  endpoint: 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/v1'
)
```